# Javascript-positioning the code result

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am using a code to give me a word, letter, whatever we want radomly starting from a list created by me. My question is, how to position the result of the code in the web page, such as the distance to the top and left? 
I thank you all the help you can give me. 
(some code words are in Portuguese so do not bind)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var c="Piso 2, lugar A1";
var d="Piso 3, lugar A2";
var e="Piso 1, lugar A3";
var thing = window['cde'.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*3))];
document.write('Reservado em ' + thing);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you'll want to put it into an element...

```
document.innerHTML = "<div>Reservado em " + thing + "</div>";
var div = document.querySelector("div");
div.setAttribute("style", "top:" TOP + "px; left:" + LEFT + "px;");
```

Something like that. Then, of course, set the top and left to your specifications.

**Revisiting old answer to offer a more proper solution:**

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.style.top = "100px";
newDiv.style.left = "100px";

document.querySelector("body").appendChild(newDiv);
```

Comment: It's not working, probably I'm doing something wrong, can you just show me how the all code would look like?Thank's for answering!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fbYwB/2/ -- I forgot to absolute-position the div in my answer, but you can see it in this jsFiddle. It's really basic stuff. You should go learn HTML/CSS before you take on javascript.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Great help! To finish, can you just tell me how can I change the size and font of the words? One more time, thank you so much for all the help.

Comment: Learn CSS. That goes far beyond this question's scope.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply put it inside a styled HTML element like this?

```
document.getElementById("random").innerHTML="Mas mas mas, por favor: " + thing;
```

Comment: Thank's for the idea!

Comment: Let me know how it goes and if my idea checks out.